# Why are voltage and volt both are denoted by $V$?

Tags: electricity, potential, voltage, conventions, si-units

Why are voltage and volt both are denoted by $V$? Won't it cause confusion?

Answer (score 0):

*Volt* is the unit of measurement of *Voltage*. There's no possible confusion. The *voltage* is the physical quantity that we measure, using a multimeter for example, and the result of that measurement is given in *Volts*.

If you have a 9V battery you're implicitly saying that if you measure the voltage across the leads of the battery, you'll measure 9 Volts.

Answer (score 0):

For this same reason some texts denote Voltage by $v$ and Volt by $V$.

Historically Volt was named after Alessandro Giuseppe Antonio Anastasio Volta to honour his remarkable work.

Further I think the denoted of Voltage by $V$ was started by Sir Pierre-Simon Laplace. Since then $V$ has been used for denoting Voltage.

---

I don't think it causes much confusion as long as you know what you are talking about.